# Why did my JavaScript code stop working when I wrote HTML code inside my JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a card slider with increment and decrement buttons using only vanilla JS.
I'm following a tutorial for the increment and decrement buttons part, And while following the tutorial I transferred my cards from my HTML file into an object inside JS and wrote the HTML code inside JS so that I can use template literals. My left and right buttons were working fine when I had my cards in my HTML file, But when I transferred the HTML code, My left and right buttons stopped working and my increment and decrement buttons also don't want to work.

This is the HTML code that's in my HTML file for the card slider.

```html
<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
  <ul class="carousel">
  </ul>
  <div class="button-wrapper">
    <button class="fa fa-angle-left fa-3x" id="left"></button>
    <button class="fa fa-angle-right fa-3x" id="right"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the code in my JS file.

```js
const carousel = document.querySelector(".carousel"),
  firstImg = carousel.querySelectorAll(".card")[0],
  arrowIcons = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper .fa");

arrowIcons.forEach((icon) => {
  icon.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let firstImgWidth = firstImg.clientWidth - -20;
    carousel.scrollLeft += icon.id == "left" ? -firstImgWidth : firstImgWidth;
  });
});

let shop = document.getElementById("wrapper");

let shopItemsData = [
  {
    id: "one",
    name: "Banana",
    price: 3.5,
    desc: "Ecuador",
    img: "download (6).png",
  },
  {
    id: "two",
    name: "Organic Loaf",
    price: 5,
    desc: "UAE",
    img: "downloadd.png",
  },
  {
    id: "three",
    name: "Pumpkin",
    price: 6.3,
    desc: "USA",
    img: "download (3).png",
  },
  {
    id: "four",
    name: "Strawberry",
    price: 10,
    desc: "Egypt",
    img: "download (4).png",
  },
  {
    id: "five",
    name: "Papaya",
    price: 8,
    desc: "Kenya",
    img: "download (2).png",
  },
  {
    id: "six",
    name: "Orange",
    price: 3.75,
    desc: "Spain",
    img: "download (5).png",
  },
];

let generateShop = () => {
  return (shop.innerHTML = shopItemsData
    .map((x) => {
      let { id, name, price, desc, img } = x;
      return `
        <li class="card" id=product-id-${id}>
            <img src="${img}" alt="" class="card-img">
                <div class="details">
                    <h2>${name}</h2>
                    <p>${desc}</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit, Ipsum, dicta!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="price-quantity">
                    <p class="description">${price} AED</p>
                    <button class="btn">
                        <span onclick="increment()" class="material-symbols-outlined">add</span>
                        <div id=${id} class="quantity">0</div>
                        <span onclick="decrement()" class="material-symbols-outlined">remove</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
        </li>
               `;
    })
    .join(""));
};

generateShop();

let increment = () => {
  console.log("increment");
};

let decrement = () => {
  console.log("decrement");
};

let update = () => {};
```

I thought my left and right buttons weren't working because my carousel and wrapper are in my HTML file and my card is in JS, But when I put them all together in JS their positions got messed up, and the buttons still didn't work.

And I'm supposed to get the words increment and decrement on my console when I click the buttons, but nothing happens, And I can't seem to figure out why? (I stopped the tutorial until I fix these issues first).

I would be grateful if somebody could help me figure this out.

Comment: `shop = document.getElementById("wrapper")` and `shop.innerHTML = ...` - you're replacing the content of the div containing the buttons, so, the buttons will disappear .... perhaps you meant `shop = document.querySelector("#wrapper .carousel")`

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains multiple errors. First of it you are changing the HTML for the wrong div. You're targeting the wrong wrapper. When your call `generateShop()` you're deleting the buttons and the carousel container.

When you call

```
let shop = document.getElementById("wrapper");
```

You should call instead

```
let shop = document.getElementsByClassName("carousel")[0];
```

Another thing try to put some text on your buttons because you can't see them properly.

When you generate your item don't put two clickable span inside the same button. You can assign the same event listener or a different one for each of them.

For more help please provide a jsfiddle with your full code and CSS of it.

Answer (score -1):

I finally managed to make the codes work together. I'll post my solution here, In hopes that it can help someone else.

My html:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="shop" id="shop"></ul>
    <div class="button-wrapper">
        <button class="fa fa-angle-left fa-3x" id="left"></button>
        <button class="fa fa-angle-right fa-3x" id="right"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

My JS:

```js
let shop = document.getElementById("shop");

let basket = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data")) || [];

let generateShop = () => {
    return (shop.innerHTML= shopItemsData
        .map((x) => {
            let {id, name, price, desc, img, perr} = x;
            let search = basket.find((x) => x.id === id ) || [];
        return `
        <li id="product-id-${id}" class="item">
        <img src="${img}" alt="" class="card-img">
        <div class="details">
            <h3>${name}</h3>
            <p>${desc}</p>
            <div class="price-quantity">
                <h3>${price} &nbsp AED</h3>
                <p class="perr">${perr}</p>
                <button class="btn">
                    <span onclick="increment(${id})" class="material-symbols- 
rounded">add</span>
                    <div id=${id} class="quantity">
                    ${search.item === undefined ? 0 : search.item}
                    </div>
                    <span onclick="decrement(${id})" class="material-symbols- 
rounded">remove</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </li>
    `
    }).join(""))
 }

generateShop();

let increment = (id) => {
    let selectedItem = id;
    let search = basket.find((x) =>x.id === selectedItem.id);

    if(search === undefined) {
        basket.push({
            id: selectedItem.id,
            item: 1,
        });
    } else {
        search.item += 1;
    }

    update(selectedItem.id);

    localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(basket));
};

let decrement = (id) => {
    let selectedItem = id;
    let search = basket.find((x) =>x.id === selectedItem.id);

    if (search === undefined) return;
    else if (search.item === 0) return;
    else {
        search.item -= 1;
    }

    update(selectedItem.id);
    basket = basket.filter((x) => x.item !== 0);

    localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(basket));
};

let update = (id) => {
    let search = basket.find((x) => x.id === id);

    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = search.item;
    calculation();
};

let calculation = () => {
    let cartIcon = document.getElementById("cartAmount");
    cartIcon.innerHTML = basket.map((x) => x.item).reduce ((x, y) => x + y, 0);
};

calculation();


const carousel = document.querySelector(".shop"),
firstImg = carousel.querySelectorAll(".item")[0],
arrowIcons = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper .fa");

arrowIcons.forEach(icon => {
    icon.addEventListener("click", () => {
        let firstImgWidth = firstImg.clientWidth - -30;        
        carousel.scrollLeft += icon.id == "left" ? -firstImgWidth : 
firstImgWidth;
    });
});
```

I put my items in a separate JS file:

```js
let shopItemsData = [{
    id: "fjs",
    name: "Banana",
    price: 3.78,
    perr: "/ kg",
    desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur",
    img: "download (6).png"
}]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).